# Cpufrequtils available frequencies

Tags: cpu

/etc/init.d/cpufrequtils has the following comment

```
 and which limits to set. Both MIN_SPEED and MAX_SPEED must be values
 listed in:
   cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies
 a value of 0 for any of the two variables will disabling the use of 
 that limit variable.
```

But the file /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies does not exist for me? Do you have it? Where could I get a fitting frequency?

Best regards

Comment: If that file is available or not depends on which CPU frequency scaling driver you are using. To determine which you are using do: `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver`. My guess is that you are NOT using the acpi-cpufreq scaling driver. I am using `intel_pstate` and it does not have that file in active mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intel has stopped publishing available frequencies but you can approximate what they are:

Use these commands to see available steps and min/max:

```
$ cd /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate
$ paste <(ls *) <(cat *) | column -s $'\t' -t
max_perf_pct  100
min_perf_pct  22
no_turbo      0
num_pstates   28
status        active
turbo_pct     33

$ cd /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq
$ paste <(ls *) <(cat *) | column -s $'\t' -t
affected_cpus                             0
cpuinfo_max_freq                          3500000
cpuinfo_min_freq                          800000
cpuinfo_transition_latency                4294967295
energy_performance_available_preferences  default performance balance_performance balance_power power 
energy_performance_preference             balance_performance
related_cpus                              0
scaling_available_governors               performance powersave
scaling_cur_freq                          1939478
scaling_driver                            intel_pstate
scaling_governor                          powersave
scaling_max_freq                          3500000
scaling_min_freq                          800000
scaling_setspeed                          <unsupported>
```

From this answer I just posted on Stack Exchange: [Get all available frequency steps](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/443767/get-all-available-frequency-steps) copy and paste this function into your terminal:

```
ApproximateFrequencies () {
    NumSteps=$(cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/num_pstates)
    MinFreq=$(cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq)
    MaxFreq=$(cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq)
    LastFreq=$MinFreq
    StepRate=$((( $MaxFreq - $MinFreq ) / $NumSteps))
    for ((n=0;n<=$NumSteps;n++)); do
        echo $LastFreq
        LastFreq=$(( $LastFreq + $StepRate))
    done
}
```

Then use this to display frequencies:

```
$ ApproximateFrequencies | column
800000  1089284 1378568 1667852 1957136 2246420 2535704 2824988 3114272 3403556
896428  1185712 1474996 1764280 2053564 2342848 2632132 2921416 3210700 3499984
992856  1282140 1571424 1860708 2149992 2439276 2728560 3017844 3307128
```

If you don't have `column` installed then omit `| column` portion of command.

Comment: I only know the intel_pstate driver intimately. For it, the number of available frequencies (available pstates) is found via: `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/num_pstates`. and for my older i7-2600K, it is 23.

Comment: @DougSmythies Thanks. Mine is 28 I'll change "dozen" to "two dozen" :) BTW our old `rm-kernels` needs an update for `linux-modules` and `linux-image-unsigned`...

Comment: Re: `rm-kernels`. Yes. Sorry, I meant to bring it up with you. I have been using the one from [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/linux-purge), in the meantime. (sorry for posting here, I can not remember how to get into chat.)

Comment: @DougSmythies The one from Jarvic or Jarno or whomever? Anyway, glad it's working. I had problems even installing Ubuntu kernels for a couple of months and then let the revisions slide back. I had other ideas too like only running update-grub / update-initramfs once after 10 kernels were removed instead of once for each kernel. I don't go into chat much either but I'll pop in there now: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room

Comment: Thanks guys, setting it to an arbitrary frequency works! For me it says I have 37 states, so it was not unlikely to hit one.
And yes, I'm using the intel_pstate driver which should explain the not existing file.